# inequality problem tough - putnam level

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have a necklace of n beads. Each bead is
labeled with an integer and the sum of all these labels
is $n − 1$. Prove that we can cut the necklace to form a
string whose consecutive labels $x_1, x_2,\dots, x_n$ satisfy
$\sum_{i=1}^k
x_i \le k −1$ for $k = 1,2,\dots,n$

Comment: I find this hard to believe - do you have a good reason to think it's true?

Comment: I've seen this problem somewhere before (possibly on here) but can't remember the context; where does this come from?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I was trying to think of a counter-example, but it looks like it works. Can you think of one?

Comment: Apply the duplicate to $y_k = 1- x_k$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm missing your point... maybe if I knew what "duplicate" you were referring to I'd see why we should apply it?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich [The question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2523484/interesting-property-of-finite-integer-sequence-with-sum-1) this one is marked as a duplicate of. There we have a finite integer sequence $(y_k)_{1\leqslant k \leqslant n}$ with sum $1$ and look for a cyclic permutation such that all partial sums are positive. Here we look for a cyclic permutation of $(x_k)_{1\leqslant k \leqslant n}$ with sum $n-1$ such that the $k^{\text{th}}$ partial sum is $\leqslant k-1$. The relation $y_k = 1 - x_k$ for $1\leqslant k \leqslant n$ converts each into the other.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah, thanks. At this end this question doesn't currently appear to  be marked as a duplicate, hence my confusion.